# last line handling in bash while loop

Tags: bash

I have a file which contains following 10 numbers:

```
> cat numbers
9
11
32
88
89
90
95
104
118
120
>
```

I would like to print out the preceding number only if it is at least 5 numbers smaller than the current number. So I expect output like this:

```
11
32
90
95
104
120
```

I have a script which does this:

```
> cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

subtraction="5"

while read -r number; do

  if [ -n "$previous_number" ] && (( $((number - subtraction)) >= previous_number )); then
    echo "$previous_number"
  fi

  previous_number="$number"

done < "$1"
> ./test.sh numbers 
11
32
90
95
104
>
```

However, it doesn't print `120`. What is the most elegant/proper solution in such cases? Should I simply add `tail -1 "$1"` after the while loop?

Comment: There's **absolutely** no need for a `tail` -- the last number will be in `$number` when the loop ends, even if that line of the file had no trailing newline (and was thus not a valid UNIX textfile line) and thus `read` returned false for it.

Comment: Aside: Don't use a `.sh` extension for bash scripts; this implies that they can be run with `sh scriptname`, which they can't (needs to be `bash scriptname` to guarantee availability of extensions). Better to have no extension at all, or, if you *must* use an extension, to use `.bash`.; see http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/ for a treatise on the subject.

Comment: BTW, using `bash -x test.sh` would have shown you the execution line-by-line, so you could see `120` being assigned to `previous_number`, and thus have known already that the `read` really *was* processing the last line.

Comment: ...that said, I'm not sure how to handle this question, since it's a logic/math/input problem, **not** actually a question about how the last line in a `while read` loop is treated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For someone else reading this for whom `while read` *genuinely is not* iterating over the last line of a file, there's a likely different problem: An input file without a trailing newline.

For **that**, one can amend their code as follows:

```
while read -r number || [[ $number ]]; do
  : "...logic here..."
done
```

This is true because without a trailing newline, `read` will return false, and so the body of the loop will not be executed with the original code, but `$number` is still populated.

---

However, for this specific program and its specific input given, there's nothing at all wrong with how the `while read` idiom handles the last line of an input; the output at hand follows from the program's logic as written and defined.

Consider the following version, which makes what's happening more clear:

```
#!/bin/bash
subtraction="5"
while read -r number; do
  if [[ $previous_number ]] && (( (number - subtraction) >= previous_number )); then
    printf '%q is at least %q away from %q\n' "$previous_number" "$subtraction" "$number"
  else
    printf '%q is not %q away from %q\n' "$previous_number" "$subtraction" "$number"
  fi
  previous_number="$number"
done <"$1"
```

Its output is:

```
'' is not 5 away from 9
9 is not 5 away from 11
11 is at least 5 away from 32
32 is at least 5 away from 88
88 is not 5 away from 89
89 is not 5 away from 90
90 is at least 5 away from 95
95 is at least 5 away from 104
104 is at least 5 away from 118
118 is not 5 away from 120
```

...as this last line of output shows, it *is* genuinely considering `120`, and deciding not to print it per your program's logic as defined.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to use `awk` for this job:

```
awk 'NR>1 && $1-p>=5{print p} {p=$1}' file
```

**Output:**

```
11
32
90
95
104
```

btw `120` won't be printed in output because preceding number is `118` which is not `<=5` to `120`.

Comment: Terser, sure. Faster for large files, sure. Capable of handling floating-point values in input, sure. "Better" is a judgment call. :)